# Why are Vashishtha and Parashara used as gotras but Shakiti is not?

Tags: vashishta, gotra, parashara

Why are *Vashishtha* and *Parashara* used as [gotras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Brahmin_gotras) but Shakiti is not? Even though they are of the same male lineage? [Vashishtha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vasishtha) > [Shakti Muni](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C5%9Aakti_Mahar%E1%B9%A3i) > [Parashara](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parashara) > [Vyas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bias_Brahmin).

Why do people not use Vashishtha as their gotra instead of Parashara or Vyas?

Comment: Dynasties either get divided or change it's name after prominent figures like ChandravVamsha got divided into Yadavas and Paurvas...and then Puaurvas became BharatVamshi, Kaaurvas, Pandavas..Yadavas became Vrishney, Madhvas, Andhakas, Bhojas..SuryaVamsh became IkshvankuVamsh and RaghuVamsh etc..few of above examples are divisions and few just rename..